# Create an array of two variables from netCDF file in R?

Tags: arrays, r, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to create an array with two variables (windspeed and wind direction) from a large netCDF file.  I have created a file name and an nc object with the netcdf4 and easyNCDF package as follows:

```
fn <- "/Volumes/AMANDACR6/Indo/Flux work/IPR/IPR/Data/IPR_ISD.nc"
nc <- nc_open(fn)
```

But I'm stuck on how to read the two variables I want into an R array.  I have managed to read one in using the following:

(Note wind direction is Wd_0 and wind speed is Ws_0)

```
a_from_file <- NcToArray(fn, vars_to_read = "Wd_0")
```

Although I'm not 100% sure it has worked correctly.  But when I try to include wind speed as well I have no luck.

```
a_from_file <- NcToArray(fn, vars_to_read = "Wd_0", "Ws_0")
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not including Ws_0 in the correct way.  Does anyone know how I can format this to read in both variables into the same array?  (For context, the ultimate purpose is to be able to create a windrose).

I'm sorry I am unable to create a reproducible example.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you not read them separately into 2 variables then combine into a data frame?

Comment: Surely you want `a_from_file <- NcToArray(fn, vars_to_read = c("Wd_0", "Ws_0"))` (with different variables you want in a vector, otherwise it will think `"WS_0"` is a different parameter